# Clarify role of list monad operator

Tags: haskell, monads, pointfree

I came across a Haskell function that tells whether a list is sorted, and I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

The code in question is

```
f = zipWith (<=) <*> tail
```

which I understand to be equivalent (in point-ful style) to

```
f' xs = zipWith (<=) xs (tail xs)
```

and as an example returns

```
f [4, 5, 1] == [True,False]
```

I take it that it has something to do with the list monad and sequential application, but would appreciate if someone could make the meaning more clear to me. What exactly is `<*>` doing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<*>` here isn't acting on the `[a]` applicative, it's acting in the `(->) a` applicative instance.

Essentially

```
 instance Applicative ((->) a) where
   pure = const -- same as monadic return
   f <*> a = \x -> f x (a x)
```

So it acts like function application, but also wraps the application in a function and gives the argument to both sides.

So expanding your function

```
 zipWith (<=) <*> tail
 \x -> zipWith (<=) x (tail x)
 \(x:xs) -> zipWith (<=) (x:xs) xs
```

In general it's correct to view `<*>` as just function application + some extra goodies. You can almost read it as whitespace!

Comment: Thanks! Your definition made it a lot clearer for me than the type signature from ghci (`f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`) which reminds me more of `map`. Is there a name for `((->) a)` for easier searching?

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV Sadly not really, That's what Reader is under the covers though.

Answer (score 7):

`<*>` is actually from `(->) a` as Applicative Functor. It is a S-combinator which distributes the argument (list `xs` in your expansion) to two functions (`zipWith (<=)` and `tail`) in the manner that you specified in the expansion: `(f <*> g) x = f x (g x)`.

To understand this, you need to check the type `(<*>)` is applied to. Since both of its arguments are `a->b`, we are talking about `a->b` as Applicative Functor - not List.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about the "canonical" version of S. S actually *is* `\xyz.xz(yz)`, so it agrees with `<*>`.

Comment: @chi second that. `f (g x) x` is actually `(f =<< g) x`.

Comment: @WillNess it looks like the edit was confusing, because `(f <*> g) x` appears expanded in two different ways in the same sentence. I'll fix that now.